# How to resolve error "Cannot resolve symbol ==="

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, squeryl

I have a simple CRUD project in scalatra and as ORM I use squeryl. I want to create some tables which are in relation each other. On this line:

```
val questionToAnswer = CustomTypesMode.oneToManyRelation(questions,answers) via ((q,a) => q.id === a.question)
```

I have compile error:

> Cannot resolve symbol ===

My dependences are:

```
val scalatraVersion = "2.4.0-RC2-2"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scalatra" %% "scalatra" % scalatraVersion,
  "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-webapp" % "9.3.0.M2",
  "org.scalaquery" % "scalaquery_2.9.1" % "0.10.0-M1",
  "org.squeryl" % "squeryl_2.8.0" % "0.9.5-RC2",
  "joda-time" % "joda-time" % "2.9.1",
  "postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.1-901.jdbc4",
  "org.eclipse.jetty.orbit" % "javax.servlet" % "3.0.0.v201112011016")
```

My IDE is intellij Idea 14.1.5.
My Schema is:

```
object AppSchema extends Schema{
  val questions = table[Question]
  val answers = table[Answer]
  val questionToAnswer = CustomTypesMode.oneToManyRelation(questions,answers) via ((q,a) => q.id === a.question)
}

case class Question (
               id:Long,
               title:String,
               content: String,
               rank: Int,
               createdDate: DateTime,
               updatedDate: Option[DateTime]
                 ){
  lazy val answers = AppSchema.questionToAnswer.left(this)
}

case class Answer(
            id: Long,
            content: String,

            rank: Int,
            createdDate: DateTime,
            updatedDate: Option[DateTime]
              ){
  lazy val question = AppSchema.questionToAnswer.right(this)
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Why it can not resolve symbol "==="

Comment: Both `2.8.0` and `2.9.1` are _very_ old Scala versions. Current Scala version is 2.11.7. You also nearly always want to write something like `"org.scalaquery" %% "scalaquery"` which will get the version corresponding to your `scalaVersion`.

Answer (score 3):

What version of scala are you using?

```
"org.scalaquery" % "scalaquery_2.9.1" % "0.10.0-M1",
"org.squeryl" % "squeryl_2.8.0" % "0.9.5-RC2",
```

THese two libraries have been compiled with different versions of scala. This can lead to unexpected behavior during compilation. You should stick to binaries compiled with a single scala version.

Answer (score 3):

I agree on keeping a consistent Scala version, and I also want to point out that the === operator is introduced by implicit conversion.  To have that implicit conversion in scope, you need to import org.squeryl.PrimitiveTypeMode._ where you use it.